# PrimeNG treetable. Conditionally change style of row

Tags: styles, row, primeng, primeng-treetable

I would like to conditionally change the style of a row in the PrimeNG TreeTable.
I have tried various options such as:`[rowStyleClass]="rowStyle()"`

But I get this error:
`Can't bind to 'rowStyleClass' since it isn't a known property of 'p-treeTable'`

Any ideas on how to change the row style conditionally?

Answer (score 0):

This feature is currently not supported by PrimeNG. But a feature request has been submitted: https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/2441.